# SMTP authentication error: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, sasl, smtp-auth, cyrus

I have a VPS server which is running postfix + dovecot as mail server.
I have already created two accounts which work well. Both can send and receive email via STARTTLS and SSL.

But when I added a third account today, it can only receive email but failed to connect SMTP server. So it is not a issue of wrong password. The SMTP settings are same as the other two accounts. The settings of client should be correct.

The postfix log says:

```
Aug 28 12:55:32 server postfix/smtpd[1645]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Aug 28 12:55:32 server postfix/smtpd[1645]: warning: unknown[203.97.197.232]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Aug 28 12:55:35 server postfix/smtpd[1645]: warning: unknown[203.97.197.232]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

The sasl and tls settings in main.cf is:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you very much.